# SharePoint 2010 item level Auditing

Tags: logging, sharepoint-2010

We are trying to get item level auditing in SharePoint to show which item was viewed (like what id the item had). Now we only get that information on the aspx of the view, not the item viewed. Is there a way to get this added to the audit log?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the site collection level settings - View/Edit....
Yet at times the full blown SharePoint auditing may not capture the details or will capture it under an event which is not obvious.
Look at the AuditData table in the content database for synthesizing the source of the audit log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up item level auditing by following the below given steps:

1. Go to the Site Settings page for the top-level site in the site collection
2. On Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration section, click the Site Collection Audit Settings link
3. Configure Audit Settings page, identify any audit log trimming settings,and select the items to audit

Get more help from here: http://sharepointthomas.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in.html )

And if you want to retrieve audit data in code you can use SPAudit.GetEntries - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457256(v=office.14).aspx  ).